# vuetify v-slider Anyway to get the new value after changing the position?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-slider

my v-slider is binded with the value of an audio progress() function

```
      <v-slider id="progress" @click.native="setPosition()" color="#464898" :value="trackProgress"></v-slider>
```

when the user move the slider , I need to get the new position but as I did not set a v-model I cannot get it ...
If a  set a v-model="percentage", then I can get the position BUT I'll lost the :value property link...

```
computed: {
   trackProgress() {
     return this.progress * 100;
   },

  methods: {
    setPosition() {
      const currentDuration = parseInt(this.duration * this.percentage);
      this.setSeek(currentDuration);
      this.play();
    }
  },
```

I m looking for a one-way data binding , slider => value on each progress so when I click on the slider I get the clicked position ....

Comment: Did you try to use the `change` event?

Comment: Yes i did ..  but i don’t get the value

Comment: I have a simple codepen example where the slider has only `@change` event and its being tracked successfully. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xayBYp

Comment: @joe . thanks a lot solved it with your help ... I should use ONLY change event , not click event   Post it as an answer I'll vote for it

Answer (score 2):

You can check start, end and change events. These events happen when user drag and drop the value.

Other way to check the value is adding a watcher to value, you can access de old and new value into watcher functions.

I hope that It works.

Comment: can you please add some smaple code for @end usage